# Supplying arguments to an image-generation program

Tags: html, get, put

We have a web application that creates a web page. In one section of the page, a graph is diplayed. The graph is created by calling graphing program with an "img src=..." tag in the HTML body. The graphing program takes a number of arguments about the height, width, legends, etc., and the data to be graphed. The only way we have found so far to pass the arguments to the graphing program is to use the GET method. This works, but in some cases the size of the query string passed to the grapher is approaching the 2058 (or whatever) character limit for URLs in Internet Explorer. I've included an example of the  tag below. If the length is too long, the query string is truncated and either the program bombs or even worse, displays a graph that is not correct (depending on where the truncation occurs).

The POST method with an auto submit does not work for our purposes, because we want the image inserted on the page where the grapher is invoked. We don't want the graph displayed on a separate web page, which is what the POST method does with the URL in the "action=" attribute.

Does anyone know a way around this problem, or do we just have to stick with the GET method and inform users to stay away from Internet Explorer when they're using our application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have the page put data into the session, then have the img generation script pull from that session information. For example page stores $_SESSION['tempdata12345'] and creates an img src="myimage.php?data=tempdata12345". Then myimage.php pulls from the session information.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have the web application that generates the entire page to pre-emptively
call the actual graphing program with all the necessary parameters.
Perhaps store the generated image in a /tmp folder.
Then have the web application create the web page and send it to the browser with a "img src=..." tag that, instead of referring to the graphing program, refers to the pre-generated image.